# Find a Random Picture from Gallery

Tags: android, random, image-gallery

I'm working on an android application that needs to obtain a **random picture** from the Gallery on an android device. Problem is I've only been able to find ways of interacting with the gallery that allows the user to chose what picture they want.

Anybody has any ideas what I should do to make this work? Java code would be helpful.

Comment: You better post some code that you already have tried! Other than that your question is to abstract!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3021018/1001401) method, then throw the IDs into an Array and just use the Random object to get a random integer from 0 to array size.

Comment: That works, but I'm still left with a
[big problem / question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13612376/change-image-to-a-picture-in-gallery).

I think knowing what is contained within "ImageColumns.DATA" might solve that problem, but I don't know.