# Get any image from android phone gallery and use in a ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, gallery, android-gallery

I have an `ImageView` in my XML code and I want my application to open this `ImageView` filled with one of the images I have in my gallery (without I choose one).

I would also like this to work on any android phone (or most of them).

I was trying something like this.

```
principalActivity_iv_UltimaFoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.principalActivity_iv_UltimaFoto);
File imagensGaleria = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
File[] listaImagens = imagensGaleria.listFiles();
principalActivity_iv_UltimaFoto.setImageURI(Uri.parse(listaImagens[0].toString()));
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is exactly your problem? What isn't working?

Comment: Your question is a possible duplicate. Please look around. Here's one to start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571651/find-a-random-picture-from-gallery

Comment: @Alfergon, I need to pick a random image from my gallery without interact. When I open my application it will load an image in my ImageView.

Comment: @AndyFaizan I will try this option. Sorry if is duplicate. I always try to find an answer and this is the first time I didn't found. I will back later and answer if this option will do what I want. Thanks :)

Comment: I'm trying to solve this problem since I posted this question but I'm with some difficult. I will continue until I solve my problem and I will come back here to post the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.
Finally I solved my question.

First I create a cursor and get all the images I have in my gallery phone and get the last photo I took.

```
Cursor cursor = pickLastPhotoAlbum();
```

After I move the cursor to first line, get the quantity of lines the cursor returned and create a Drawable.

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
int qtd = cursor.getCount();
Drawable backgroundGaleria;
```

Third I made an if to see if my cursor is null or not.

If is null I get a drawable image that I have in my imgs folder.

If is not null I get the path of the image, set my drawable from path and set the background of my ImageView with this drawable.

```
if (qtd > 0){
    String imageGallery = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/Tubagram/" + cursor.getString(1)+".png";
    backgroundGaleria = Drawable.createFromPath(imageGallery);
    principalActivity_iv_UltimaFoto.setBackground(backgroundGaleria);
}else{
    principalActivity_iv_UltimaFoto.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.box_imagem_album);
}
```

To the image doesn't overflow his size you need to set the width and height (I set min, normal size and max) using XXXdp.

```
android:layout_width="61dp"
android:layout_height="42dp"
```

And here is the method who returns values to my cursor

```
private Cursor pickLastPhotoAlbum(){
    final ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
final String[] p1 = new String[] {
    MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
    MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.TITLE,
    MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN
};
Cursor c1 = cr.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, p1, null, null, p1[1] + " DESC");

if (c1.moveToFirst() ) {
    Log.i("Teste", "last picture (" + c1.getString(1) + ") taken on: " + new Date(c1.getLong(2)));
}

    Log.i("Caminho download imagem", "file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/Tubagram/"  + c1.getString(1) + ".png");

return c1;
}
```

Thanks to everyone who helped me with this.