# how to get list of all photos in android?

Tags: android

How can I get list of all images on the phone and show all of them in a listview. Basically I have a dialog where I am asking for a album name and a photo name which will be populated with the selection made from the listview. How do I get the file URI using this code...

[Android list all images available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020478/android-list-all-images-available/3021018#3021018)

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_IMAGE);
```

Answer (score 3):

In answer to another question, hpique answered that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4495753/793607):

```
public static List<String> getCameraImages(Context context) {
    final String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    final String selection = MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID + " = ?";
    final String[] selectionArgs = { CAMERA_IMAGE_BUCKET_ID };
    final Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
            projection, 
            selection, 
            selectionArgs, 
            null);
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>(cursor.getCount());
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        final int dataColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        do {
            final String data = cursor.getString(dataColumn);
            result.add(data);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I get nothing... from the above code.

Comment: hmmm.... I must have misled you.  That is the code for viewing all the pictures you've taken on an Android.  I guess that must not be what you meant.

Comment: Perhaps gubatron's answer will help you:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/3021018/793607

Comment: but do I use gubatron's answer to populate my listview..

Comment: Yes, you should use his answer to populate your listView

Comment: I just updated my question could you tell me how do i get the file uri from the intent...

Comment: I am not understanding your question.